# Running jQuery without document.ready() -and crashing ie 8

Tags: jquery, crash

here is a very simplified example of what happened

```
jQuery(".resultAction").each(makeItso);

function makeItso() {
    //code executes (it was a conditional to test for a file extension and display apply a class)
    //the short version:
    jQuery(this).find("#indicator").addClass("is" + fileExtension.slice(1));

    //no file extension hide the icon div "indicator"
    if ((fileExtension.indexOf('.') == -1)) {
        jQuery(this).find("#indicator").addClass("not");
    }

}
```

Now, this worked well and it worked faster than .ready() -as I had about 100 results per page.

but there was one bug: on the last element it did not execute -so, I did this to re-run the function on that last item after the page loaded:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".resultAction:last").each(makeItso);
});
```

So, to make a long story short this worked well, in Firefox, IE 7,8, 9 -though HERE is the interesting part: I tested using a Mac and VMware Fusion, sop I "thought" I was OK, the testers used their PC's and IE 8 --Epic fail.

I leaned something: #1 testing on a Virtual machine is NOT the same as the real deal. Also my Question is why did this crash In IE 8 and otherwise run fine in 9 and in Fox? Did I code badly?

Comment: Can you provide (a simplified version of) the HTML? Or ideally a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.com) that crashes IE directly?

Comment: that would be hard to do -because it will allways run well with a hard coded example. basically, I have a div with a .resultaction class, inside it I have an #indicator div -in the real world there are many server generated results, The mystery is 1) why it ran well to begin with in my testing environment and then 2) why would IE 8 particularly barf it up? Also there is some css applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have an element with `id="indicator"` inside every `.resultAction`. Each ID should be unique on the page. Some browsers may not care about this restriction. Others might.

Change the `id="indicator"` to be `class="indicator"` and it may help.

As for your other problem, that it isn't executing on the last row, you don't need to wait for document.ready as long as you make sure the script comes later in the HTML than the elements it is manipulating. I.e. put the `<script>` tag last thing before the body. If you are doing this and it isn't working, we'll definitely need to see the full html.

Comment: OK we found the culprit, first we got rid of this script and introduced a server side solution, Next we found a the REAL culprit:another script I added having an "each" invoked was looping through about 1000+ results crashing the browser. Locally, I didn't see it because my test environment had fewer Data results to play with, Hence why it crashed later when QC got ahold of it. Live and learn...